# How to connect the css?

Tags: django

How can I plug css into html by importing css from the main folder? I have a network project with 3 app.

```
network
   --chat
   --news
   --static/style.css
   ...
```

My code:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% style.css' %}">
```

It works if I create a static folder in some app, but I want to put it in the main network folder and then it stops working.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `settings.py`;

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
```

Then inside your html files;

```
{% load static %}

<link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'styles.css' %}">
```

**Explanation**

first of all i am setting the `STATIC_URL` which helps in the way that everytime you don't need to provide the path of the static files but use the syntax as i used (`"{% static 'styles.css' %}"`).

After that i set the `STATICFILES_DIRS`  which sets the directories where the app should search for the static files which i set to the `static` folder present in the base directory. You can set it as you want.